# Using Chrome Extension contextMenu, how to open a small view right next to the context menu on click?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

This question has a couple bits to it. Basically I want to make the context menu behave like a sidebar that pops out a box with html.

1. Get the height and location of a users context menu?
2. Open an interactable html view next to the menu without closing the menu?
3. Close both the menu and popout on off-click.

So a user can right click on the page,

[image]

and then click the contextMenu item to open a page that can hold html
[image]

Comment: A picture might help.

Comment: @Xan, thx, added images to help. Cheers